# Determine Long & Lat for Google street view camera

Tags: google-street-view

Is it possible to determine the Longitude and Latitude of the Google Earth Street View Camera  so as to triangulate the location of an object in a street view image?

Answer (score 1):

Given the position of the object you can use the Street View Service API to find a nearby panorama, from this panorama object you can get its lat/lng position as in the following example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-events